# PHP: Dynamic Pages with multiple dynamic content

Tags: php, dynamic

I'm using this a particular code to dynamically load content on a webpage.

Problem is, I want to use it to load multiple things on the same page. How do I go about making this possible? I've already isolated the problem to the fact that the second instance of the code that runs replaces the entire URL instead of appending an additional `?="pageurl"` but I'm stuck right there.

I've got a second script that uses the variable `p` instead of `b` so the browser knows to load `p`'s content in a different location.

This is what the code does: 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qg-EBdNaUbo

[edit]

Not sure why you guys can't see the link, it explains everything. I'm calling the script via a link  Here is the link again youtube.com/watch?v=Qg-EBdNaUbo

**CODE:**

```
<?php

$pages_dir = 'pages';

if(!empty($_GET['b']))
{

    $pages = scandir($pages_dir, 0);
    unset($pages [0], $pages [1]); 
    $b = $_GET['b'];

    if(in_array($b, $pages))
        {
        include($pages_dir.'/'.$b); 
        }
    else
        {
        echo 'sorry page not found';

        }
            }
else 
    {
    }   

?>
```

Comment: It's not clear how you're calling that script (and your youtube link is down). Wild guess: use `b[]=pageOne.html&b[]=pageTwo.html` as your params and iterate over the resulting array `$b`, including pages as you go.

Comment: Yeah, is not clear! could you add the URL format and a clear use case so we can help.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qg-EBdNaUbo  <-- isn't down?

Comment: Not sure why you guys can't see the link, it explains everything. I'm calling the script via a link <a href='index.php?b=newpage.php'> Here is the link again http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qg-EBdNaUbo